# Preventing <link>ed CSS file blocking downloads in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 7 (but not 8/9) blocks anything downloading until the CSS file has finished on our site.

We are not using Internet Explorer tests around it `<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->`, nor are we using protocol independent URI's (`//` instead of `http://`). It is just a straight forward `/css/global/core.css` link and yet the browser waits until it has finished downloading before commencing.

Are there any techniques to prevent this behaviour?

PS: All the JavaScript is at the bottom, all the static content is hosted on another domain (except the CSS due to it being able to reuse the existing connection after the HTML document, resulting in a faster experience for the user even with additional cookie headers).

**EDIT:**

The problem is that profiling IE7 with DynaTrace causes CSS files to block further downloads, however with DynaTrace turned off it works. So this is a DynaTrace bug, not an IE7 one.

**WITH DynaTrace:**
[image]

**WITHOUT DynaTrace:**
[image]

Comment: Unless there's some general technique which will work for your case, I think we need a link to your site to take a look at the source.

Comment: Intriguing stuff! You may want to try a tool called the "fiddler" to do your tracing, it's analytics isn't as powerful, but it is quite "low-level" so won't skew any results.

Comment: It's already part of my arsenal but thank you for the insight. If there are any tools (beyond PageSpeed/Chrome/DynaTrace/DragonFly) for diagnosing CSS/JS delays and execution times though that'd be great! The graphs above were created using WebPageTest.org, which allows us to try different geographical locations without paying for Gomez.

Comment: WebPageTest.org looks good - i've not used that before, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you hitting the limit for the number of parallel downloads per domain?

I believe IE7's default is 2 files per domain , whereas many newer browsers support 6 by default.

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/12/sharding-dominant-domains/

Comment: Adding a static3 (another domain) or degrading to HTTP/1.0 actually decreases page speed (both on the benchmark scores and visually in IETester) on this website. IE7 staggers the downloads (and spends a long time creating new connections for each download) even when it could open enough sockets to download all resources in parallel. Although this behaviour does not affect all sites that I maintain.

Comment: Are you using CNAME's? As that *may* affect things - as it'll cause a double domain name lookups... I wonder if IE7 will treat CNAME's as a single domain?